# Apollo/GraphIQL Shows "Apollo Server supports only POST requests"?

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo-server

I've installed Apollo/GraphQL. When I access GraphiQL at http://localhost:8080/graphql, instead of the GraphiQL user interface, I see this message:

> Apollo Server supports only POST requests.

I've installed the Apollo Server 0.2.x code specified by the docs here:

http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/migration.html

How can I get the GraphiQL user interface to show up?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any thoughts or info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you followed the instructions, graphiql will be running on `/graphiql` (note the extra 'i')

Comment: Thank you very much! The sample code in the docs at `http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-server/migration.html` logs to the console, ``GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}/graphql`` -- that's how I got the incorrect URL.

Comment: Yeah, it tells you the url the API is on. If you want, you could make a PR against the docs to add a line that says graphiql is running on /graphiql

Comment: Sounds good, @helfer. Could you post a github link for the docs so I could submit a PR?

Comment: Here's the link: https://github.com/apollostack/docs/blob/master/source/apollo-server/migration.md

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that stumbles on this like I have, there is a temporary [issue](https://github.com/apollostack/graphql-server/issues/193) in graphql-server.

That's why at the moment you cannot access graphiql at /graphql (the endpointURL you specified) given the following code:

```
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema }));
app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' }));
```

I posted here because this issue would result in the exact problem the original question was asking (hence this thread turned up as one of only a couple of search results during my troubleshooting).